# How to display markup instead of pure text in Django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to display a form that uses Font Awesome icons. I have the field `emotion` which contains `EMOTIONS` as choices, and I want to display the font awesome icon related to each option. I have tried just adding the markup (see the last option of `EMOTIONS`). However, this is rendering exactly the pure text instead of the icon.

[image]

Is it possible to display the Font Awesome icon in the way I am trying? This is my form:

```
class PreferencesForm(forms.Form):
    EMOTIONS = [
        ('', 'Joy'),
        ('', 'Sad'),
        ('', 'Angry'),
        ('', 'Tired'),
        ('', '<i class="far fa-smile"></i>'),
    ]
    FAMOUS_PEOPLE = [
        ('US', 'Abraham Lincoln'),
        ('MX', 'Frida Khalo'),
        ('IT', 'Leonardo da Vinci'),
        ('FR', 'Napoleon Bonaparte'),
        ('JP', 'Hayao Miyazaki'),
    ]

    emotion = forms.ChoiceField(choices=EMOTIONS, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    famous_person = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FAMOUS_PEOPLE, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

This is my markup:

```
<form action="." method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I display the corresponding font awesome icon instead of the markup?

I have tried `{{ form|safe }}`, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Have you tried using UTF-8 format?

Comment: @bdbd, yes, my markup is quite long containing the boilerplate which includes `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: Ok how about turning off the auto-escape? More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape

Comment: @bdbd, thanks for your comment, but it is not working. I tried, and it shows exactly as it is shown in the image I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe).

So I was struggling for an hour, and I decided to ask a question, and I was able to figure it out approximately 20 minutes after I posted it after seeing that `safe` was used in templates to render `HTML`.

Therefore, my form ended up being as follows:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class PreferencesForm(forms.Form):
    EMOTIONS = [
        ('', 'Joy'),
        ('', 'Sad'),
        ('', 'Angry'),
        ('', 'Tired'),
        ('', mark_safe('<i class="far fa-smile"></i>')),
    ]
    FAMOUS_PEOPLE = [
        ('US', 'Abraham Lincoln'),
        ('MX', 'Frida Khalo'),
        ('IT', 'Leonardo da Vinci'),
        ('FR', 'Napoleon Bonaparte'),
        ('JP', 'Hayao Miyazaki'),
    ]

    emotion = forms.ChoiceField(choices=EMOTIONS, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    famous_person = forms.ChoiceField(choices=FAMOUS_PEOPLE, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

No changes were required in the HTML.

Comment: That's weird. Turning off auto-escape should have done that automatically. But alright at least its working now.